# Is it legal on SE network for a person to have two accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

I'm currently blocked from asking any question in Physics SE, due to a few foolish questions which I had asked there (I admit the questions are foolish).

However, now I have quite a few questions, to which I need a proper answer. I have found no other site which can give proper answers like SE. So, I want to create a new account under my name and the same email.

Is this allowed in SE network? I'll never ask for merging of accounts or addition of any reputation gained in this new account. I need one urgently only to solve my questions.

*N.B.: If this is not allowed, please don't block me. I'll surely delete the question. I'm asking because I don't want to go against the site rules. I had seen one person on StackOverflow or SuperUser (I can't remember which), who had two accounts, and had written the same in his profile section. That's why I'm asking this question.*

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Is this allowed in SE network?

Given that the entire reason you want a new account is to circumvent a question ban then no, it isn't allowed. Doing so will only cause your new account to get merged into the old one - and stay banned.

---

The question ban banner has a link - to a page that explains how to get out of a ban.

Here is a link to your convenience:

[What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

I suggest reading through that and following its recommendations.

---

In general - there is no rule against someone having multiple accounts - so long as they are:

1. Not used to circumvent restrictions
2. Not interacting with each other (i.e vote for each other)

Comment: What if I don't link the accounts?

Comment: Not the point. You are the same person, are you not? And you are trying to circumvent restrictions (said question ban). What is the point of the ban if all people do is just register a new account and continue?

Comment: I will say this one more time. What you are suggesting is not allowed. Period.

Comment: OK, I understand.